# Debugger runs for 1 or 2 seconds and disappears... not working

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, launch

I'm trying to get the debugger working in vscode and it is failing to run.  I have tried using the debugger on a normal python file and also in my Django project.  Please help

```
   //launch.json
   {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "--noreload",
            "--nothreading"
        ],
        "django": true
    },
```

Comment: Please provide specific details to your problem.  In example.  What do you mean by you are trying to get debugger working?  What have you tried?  Any relative information will help you get an answer that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem after vs code updated to 1.39. I tried creating a new launch.json and all the normal restarts (computer, vs code etc...). Nothing was working so I started the process of downgrading vs code. I went into settings and changed the auto-update settings to "manual". This caused vs code to restart. Once it did this, the debugger problem went away. Not sure why this was related to the debugger, but it solved my problem.